# Issue with multiple sqlite3 inserts

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I am creating a web-based POS system.  Once the users clicks the "order submit" data is submitted via this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    transaction_id integer primary key autoincrement,
    total_price integer not null
);
CREATE TABLE order_items (
    transaction_id integer REFERENCES orders(transaction_id),
    SKU integer not null,
    product_name text not null,
    unit_price integer not null,
    quantity integer not null
);
```

Through this flask code:

```
@app.route('/load_ajax', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def load_ajax():
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.get_json()
        for group in groupby(data, itemgetter('name')):
            id, data_list = group
            for d in data_list:
                print d['subtotal']
                db = get_db()
                db.execute('insert into order_items (SKU, product_name, unit_price, quantity) values (?, ?, ?, ?); insert into orders (total_price) values (?)',
                [d['sku'], d['name'], d['price'], d['quantity']],[d['subtotal']])
                db.commit()
        return jsonify(location=url_for('thankyou'))
```

I am getting a 500 error and I'm not sure why it is happening.  Do I need to do two different db.execute statements?

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at Flask-SQLAlchemy. You won't have to write SQL queries like that inside your code.

Comment: http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/quickstart.html#a-minimal-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to use two different `.execute()` statements. Quoting the [`cursor.execute()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute):

> `execute()` will only execute a single SQL statement.

So do so:

```
db.execute('insert into order_items (SKU, product_name, unit_price, quantity) values (?, ?, ?, ?)',
           (d['sku'], d['name'], d['price'], d['quantity']))
db.execute('insert into orders (total_price) values (?)',
           (d['subtotal'],))
```